# StackExchange.Precompilation - How can I unit test precompilation diagnostics?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, roslyn, precompile

**Background**

I'm using StackExchange.Precompilation to implement aspect-oriented programming in C#.  [See my repository on GitHub.](https://github.com/jamesfaix/traction)

The basic idea is that client code will be able to place custom attributes on members, and the precompiler will perform syntax transformations on any members with those attributes.  A simple example is the `NonNullAttribute` I created.  When `NonNullAttribute` is placed on a parameter `p`, the precompiler will insert

```
if (Object.Equals(p, null)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(p));
```

at the beginning of the method body.

---

**Diagnostics are awesome...**

I would like to make it difficult to use these attributes incorrectly.  The best way I have found (aside from intuitive design) is to create compile-time `Diagnostic`s for invalid or illogical uses of attributes.

For example, `NonNullAttribute` does not make sense to use on value-typed members.  (Even for nullable value-types, because if you wanted to guarantee they weren't null then a non-nullable type should be used instead.)  Creating a `Diagnostic` is a great way to inform the user of this error, without crashing the build like an exception.

---

**...but how do I test them?**

Diagnostics are a great way to highlight errors, but I also want to make sure my diagnostic creating code does not have errors.  I would like to be able to set up a unit test that can precompile a code sample like this

```
public class TestClass {
    public void ShouldCreateDiagnostic([NonNull] int n) { }       
}
```

and confirm that the correct diagnostic is created (or in some cases that no diagnostics have been created).

Can anyone familiar with StackExchange.Precompilation give me some guidance on this?

---

**Solution:**

The answer given by @m0sa was incredibly helpful.  There are a lot of details to the implementation, so here is the unit test actually looks like (using NUnit 3).  Note the `using static` for `SyntaxFactory`, this removes a lot of clutter in the syntax tree construction.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using NUnit.Framework;
using StackExchange.Precompilation;
using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;

namespace MyPrecompiler.Tests {

    [TestFixture]
    public class NonNull_CompilationDiagnosticsTest {

        [Test]
        public void NonNullAttribute_CreatesDiagnosticIfAppliedToValueTypeParameter() {

            var context = new BeforeCompileContext {
                Compilation = TestCompilation_NonNullOnValueTypeParameter(),
                Diagnostics = new List<Diagnostic>()
            };

            ICompileModule module = new MyPrecompiler.MyModule();

            module.BeforeCompile(context);

            var diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.SingleOrDefault();

            Assert.NotNull(diagnostic);
            Assert.AreEqual("MyPrecompiler: Invalid attribute usage", 
                            diagnostic.Descriptor.Title.ToString()); //Must use ToString() because Title is a LocalizeableString
        }

        //Make sure there are spaces before the member name, parameter names, and parameter types.
        private CSharpCompilation TestCompilation_NonNullOnValueTypeParameter() {
            return CreateCompilation(
                MethodDeclaration(ParseTypeName("void"), Identifier(" TestMethod"))
                .AddParameterListParameters(
                    Parameter(Identifier(" param1"))
                        .WithType(ParseTypeName(" int"))
                        .AddAttributeLists(AttributeList()
                                            .AddAttributes(Attribute(ParseName("NonNull"))))));
        }

        //Make sure to include Using directives
        private CSharpCompilation CreateCompilation(params MemberDeclarationSyntax[] members) {

            return CSharpCompilation.Create("TestAssembly")
               .AddReferences(References)
               .AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.Create(CompilationUnit()
                    .AddUsings(UsingDirective(ParseName(" Traction")))
                    .AddMembers(ClassDeclaration(Identifier(" TestClass"))
                                .AddMembers(members))));
        }

        private string runtimePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\";

        private MetadataReference[] References =>
            new[] {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(runtimePath + "mscorlib.dll"),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(runtimePath + "System.dll"),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(runtimePath + "System.Core.dll"),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(NonNullAttribute).Assembly.Location)
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure you want to add you diagnostics before the actual emit / compilation, so the steps would be:

1. create your `CSharpCompilation`, make sure it has no diagnostic errors before going further
2. create an `BeforeCompileContext`, and populate it with the compilation and an empty `List<Diagnostic>`
3. create an instance of your `ICompileModule` and call `ICompileModule.BeforeCompile` with the context from step 2
4. check that it contains the required `Diagnostic`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am trying this out now and will report back.